# Access from AsyncTask to Application Class or any other Global variables from any Classes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences, global

I can't access from AsyncTask to Application Class, or issue with SharedPreferences with last updated data, etc..

Basically **why I need my Global variable is to keep track currently active activity**, and it should be accessable from any type of class, like **Activity**, **AsyncTask**, **Service**, **Receiver**, **Application**, Etc...

**I know there is lot of questions=answers in here, but none of those helped me.**

I tried several ways to do this, but couldn't find any real resolution for this.

With **SharedPreferences**, I can use it, but after preferences updated and readed, returned previous value, works only after restart app.

With **Application Class**, no luck, can't access to Application from AsyncTask and service

**Service** runs **AsyncTask** on every 5sec, and AsyncTask should know if MainActivity is opened and running, so it can update contents to it.

I got pretty much everything working but, with this, I spend way too many hours on searching.

So please, if anybody can help me with this, it would be nice. :)

**Here is little example how I do..**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean active = false;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        this.prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.my.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        storeActivity("MainActivity");

        this.active = true;

        ((App) this.getApplication()).setTopActivity("MainActivity");
    }

    public void storeActivity(String TOP_ACTIVITY) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("TOP_ACTIVITY", TOP_ACTIVITY);
        editor.apply();
        editor.commit();           
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((App) this.getApplication()).setTopActivity("MainActivity");
        this.active = true;
        storeActivity("MainActivity");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ((App) this.getApplication()).setTopActivity("");
        this.active = false;
        storeActivity("");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        ((App) this.getApplication()).setTopActivity(ACTIVITY_NAME);
        this.active = true;
        storeActivity("MainActivity");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        ((App) this.getApplication()).setTopActivity("");
        this.active = false;
        storeActivity("");
    }

}
```

Here is my Application Object,

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {
    private String TOP_ACTIVITY;

    public String getTopActivity() {
        return TOP_ACTIVITY;
    }
    public void setTopActivity(String CURRENT_ACTIVITY) {
        this.TOP_ACTIVITY = CURRENT_ACTIVITY;
    }
    public static Application getApplication() {
        return new App();
    }
}
```

And here is some AsyncTask getting information from server

**Socket.java**

```
public class SocketUpdater extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    public SocketUpdater(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.my.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("");
        return new String(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "RESULT: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String TOP_ACTIVITY = ((App) this.getApplication()).getTopActivity();
        // THIS CANT WORK, NO this.getApplication()!!!

        boolean MainActivityActive = MainActivity.active;
        // THIS RETURNS ME FALSE ALL THE TIME

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        String PREF_TOP_ACTIVITY = prefs.getString("TOP_ACTIVITY", "");            

        if(MainActivityActive) { 
            Toast.makeText(context, "NEVER FIRES!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if(TOP_ACTIVITY.equals("MainActivity")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "NEVER FIRES!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if(PREF_TOP_ACTIVITY.equals("MainActivity")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "NEVER FIRES!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Somehow all these returns empty string from asynctask, is there any solutions with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent days for searching what causes the problem.

I found simple solution for this, and got all methods working like I wanted.

The thing was that I had my service running own separated process like this:

```
<service android:name="fi.hgs.apps.MyService"
    android:process=":myService"
</service>
```

And just removed **android:process=":myService"** from AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Why not use "Otto" library from Square? You can send objects with ease between activity and service. I'm using it within my application for similar purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I prefer not to use any external libraries, if it's not neccesary.